# Add html text in error message using client side validation in mvc3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, client-side-validation

I have an MVC appilcation with a model which uses the `[Required]` attibute for a field.  When the validation for this attribute fails, I would like to show a hyperlink in the error message.

When I add `<a href="link">link</a>`, the text of the link is displayed as is in the error message. How can I show a link in the error message which is displayed using the `Html.ValidationMesssageFor(model=>model.attibute)`?

I am using the Razor view engine.

Can we add any style to error message in order to show the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method like the following somewhere in your solution:

```
using System.Web;
namespace MvcApplication.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlStringExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString Raw(this IHtmlString htmlString)
        {
            return new HtmlString(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in each of your views add the following using statement:

```
@using MvcApplication.Extensions
```

Or you could add the following to your web.config

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcApplication.Extensions" />
      </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Once you've done these two steps, you will be able to get an un-encoded html string, like you are looking for, by changing your ValidationMessageFor() call to:

```
Html.ValidationMesssageFor(model=>model.attibute).Raw()
```

Comment: I have tried using the above steps then to the text <a href="link">link</a> is appearing in the error message. I have created a class and wrote the above code. Then included that class on the view and added the "Raw()" as Html.ValidationMesssageFor(model=>model.attibute).Raw(). But the html text for hyperlink is appearing as is in the error message..

Answer (score 0):

The validation text is encoded before the ValidationSumary or ValidationFor, etc...

you just need tu decode the html, then create an MvcHtmlString ...

Exemple :

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary().ToString()).ToMvcHtmlString()
```

this is an extension i have made to make MvcHtmlString :

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this string value)
        {
        return System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString.Create(value);
        }
    }
 }
```

or you can create an HtmlHelper if you plan to reuse this:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class FormHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummaryEx(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors)
        {
            var original = htmlHelper.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors);
            var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(original.ToString());
            return decoded.ToMvcHtmlString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it help you or future viewer.
Note: it work for all validations Summary and ValidationFor ...